# Modify dict keys and assign to new dict

Tags: python

I have JSON data that is in the form of a list that contains multiple dictionaries. I want to create a new dictionary with the same values as the old dictionary but different keys. I am taking the original keys and removing the underscores as well as capitalizing each word. The problem is that when I am creating the new dictionary it does not create the dictionary in the same manor (see code output below).

How can I create a new dictionary with the same structure as the old one, but with modified keys?

**JSON Data**

```
contacts_to_parse = [
    {
        "contact_order": "1",
        "contact_type": "Other",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "2",
        "contact_type": "Mail Alias",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "3",
        "contact_type": "Mail Alias",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "5",
        "contact_type": "Other",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "7",
        "contact_type": "Employee",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "8",
        "contact_type": "Employee",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "9",
        "contact_type": "Other",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    }
]
```

**Code so far:**

```
def check(contacts):
    parsed_keys = []
    new_dict = {}
    for contact in contacts:
        for key, val in contact.items():
            rm_underscore_capitalize = key.replace('_', ' ').title()
            new_dict[rm_underscore_capitalize] = val
            if rm_underscore_capitalize in new_dict:
                parsed_keys.append(new_dict)
                new_dict = dict()

    return parsed_keys


if __name__ == '__main__':
    con = check(contacts_to_parse)
    print(con)
```

**Current output:**

```
[{'Contact Order': '1'}, {'Contact Type': 'Other'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, {'Contact Order': '2'}, {'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, {'Contact Order': '3'}, {'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, {'Contact Order': '5'}, {'Contact Type': 'Other'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, {'Contact Order': '7'}, {'Contact Type': 'Employee'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, {'Contact Order': '8'}, {'Contact Type': 'Employee'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, {'Contact Order': '9'}, {'Contact Type': 'Other'}, {'Contact Role': 'role here'}, {'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull some of the processing near the end of your inner loop out to the outer loop. You are trying to loop over a list of dictionaries and then loop over the keys to update the `new_dict` but you're redefining `new_dict` too often. Try this:

```
def check(contacts):
    parsed_keys = []
    for contact in contacts:
        new_dict = {}
        for key, val in contact.items():
            rm_underscore_capitalize = key.replace('_', ' ').title()
            new_dict[rm_underscore_capitalize] = val
        parsed_keys.append(new_dict)

    return parsed_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is slightly off. You want to move your conditional to outside the second for loop:

```
def check(contacts):
    parsed_keys = []
    new_dict = {}
    for contact in contacts:
        for key, val in contact.items():
            rm_underscore_capitalize = key.replace('_', ' ').title()
            new_dict[rm_underscore_capitalize] = val
        if rm_underscore_capitalize in new_dict:
            parsed_keys.append(new_dict)
            new_dict = dict()

    return parsed_keys
```

Returns:

```
[
{'Contact Order': '1', 'Contact Type': 'Other',      'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, 
{'Contact Order': '2', 'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias', 'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, 
{'Contact Order': '3', 'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias', 'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, 
{'Contact Order': '5', 'Contact Type': 'Other',      'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, 
{'Contact Order': '7', 'Contact Type': 'Employee',   'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, 
{'Contact Order': '8', 'Contact Type': 'Employee',   'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}, 
{'Contact Order': '9', 'Contact Type': 'Other',      'Contact Role': 'role here', 'Contact Text': 'contact text here'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you expect this? I tried to make it simple.

```
contacts_to_parse = [
    {
        "contact_order": "1",
        "contact_type": "Other",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    },
    {
        "contact_order": "2",
        "contact_type": "Mail Alias",
        "contact_role": "role here",
        "contact_text": "contact text here"
    }
]


def check(contacts):
    result = []
    for item in contacts:
        result.append({})
        for key, val in item.items():
            result[-1][key.replace('_', ' ').title()] = val
    return result


print(check(contacts_to_parse))
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        'Contact Order': '1',
        'Contact Type': 'Other',
        'Contact Role': 'role here',
        'Contact Text': 'contact text here'
    },
    {
        'Contact Order': '2',
        'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias',
        'Contact Role': 'role here',
        'Contact Text': 'contact text here'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code using a list comprehension and a dict comprehension:

```
def check(contacts):
    return [_check_contact(contact) for contact in contacts]

def _check_contact(contact):
    return {key.replace('_', ' ').title(): value for key, value in contact.items()}

from pprint import pprint
pprint (check(contacts_to_parse))
```

Result:

```
[{'Contact Order': '1',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Other'},
 {'Contact Order': '2',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias'},
 {'Contact Order': '3',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Mail Alias'},
 {'Contact Order': '5',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Other'},
 {'Contact Order': '7',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Employee'},
 {'Contact Order': '8',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Employee'},
 {'Contact Order': '9',
  'Contact Role': 'role here',
  'Contact Text': 'contact text here',
  'Contact Type': 'Other'}]
```